# Deleting secure files if program crashes

Tags: python, security, delete-file, secure-coding

I'm looking for way to delete secure files if a program were to crash in any way. Is there a way to do this in python?

I've been looking at the tempfile module to see if this were possible. Looking it over, I believe it is not suitable. I think it needs to explicitly close a file to delete it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Someone may access the files before your code finishes. (Only some file systems support locking.) Usually the file permissions for any such files would be set that only the owner can read them. That said, you could write a watchdog program that check whether the main one is still alive and then either cleans up or restarts it.

Comment: 1. You could have a second program that monitors the first program and deletes the file when it closes. 2. you could store the files in memory and write it to disk only if the program exits securely. 3. You could use an encrypted file with the keys only existing in memory.

Comment: The best way is to delete the file after you open it. When the program closes the file or exits, the file will go away. If the file is being used for communication between processes, delete it after all the processes open it.

Comment: If the application is written in python, you could register an exit handler to delete the files. This would handle any "normal" exit, including python level exceptions. But wouldn't handle something like a segfault in a C extension.